# laravel prefix not working in route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin','middleware' => 'auth_admin_check'), function() {
    Route::any("dashboard",["as"=>"admin_login_post1","uses"=>"admin\DashboardController@index"]);
});
```

after login i am redirecting to the page: dashboard but my prefix : 'admin' was not added.

Comment: You've been redirected to `/dashboard` page and it works, I mean Laravel executes `admin\DashboardController@index` method? Try to clear route cache with `php artisan route:clear` command. Do you have any other `dashboard` related routes? How do you tell Laravel where it should redirect you after login?

Comment: return redirect('dashboard');

Answer (score 2):

I think you're redirecting to a url? Do you redirect to '/dashboard'? This will not prefix it.

What you should use is

```
redirect(route('admin_login_post1'))
```

This will retrieve the url by the route's name. Laravel will find the route in a group with a prefix, so Laravel will prefix the URL.

The `route()` function is very usefull. When you change a url, you don't have to change it troughout your whole application. This is because the function retrieves the url from the routes file. So if you change it in the routes file, you change all the links in your application.

Comment: I think changing the Route::any() -> Route::post() might also be useful. Depends on what he is trying to do! Just a comment as I understood..

Comment: @RohitBhalani Good to hear. Will you be so kind to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark and/or upvoting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

if your prefix "admin" is not loading in the URL, then may be there is another route declared for /dashboard. check for that

and for redirection, use

```
redirect()->route('admin_login_post1');
```